# How to convert WorkItemCollection to a List

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, tfs

I want to convert `WorkItemCollection` to a `List<WorkItem>`, so that I could convert it further into a `dictionary`. Here's the code so far:

```
var testItemCollectionList = new List<WorkItem>();
WorkItemCollection testItemCollection;
Query query = new Query(project.Store, "Select [Title] From WorkItems", testResults.Select(item => item.TargetId).ToArray());
var car = query.BeginQuery();
testItemCollection = query.EndQuery(car);
testItemCollectionList = ???;
var testItemMapQuery = testItemCollectionList.ToDictionary(w => w, createItemFromQuery);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
testItemCollectionList = (from WorkItem mItem in testItemCollection select mItem).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Since `WorkItemCollection` implements `IEnumerable` through `ReadOnlyList`, you should be able to use `.Cast<WorkItem>()` then directly convert to a `Dictionary`.

```
var testItemMapQuery = testItemCollection.Cast<WorkItem>()
                                         .ToDictionary(w => w, createItemFromQuery);
```